# Crash AVFoundation in +[AVOutputContext(FigRoutingContext) currentRoutingContextFactory]

Tags: ios, crash, avfoundation, airplay, mpvolumeview

We have crash in AVFoundation.

AVFoundation
+[AVOutputContext(FigRoutingContext) currentRoutingContextFactory]

EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000a3c27beb8

```
Crashed: Thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x183b8c910 objc_msgSend + 16
1  AVFoundation                   0x18a5401bc +[AVOutputContext(FigRoutingContext) currentRoutingContextFactory] + 56
2  AVFoundation                   0x18a53ae28 +[AVFigRoutingContextOutputContextImpl sharedAudioPresentationOutputContext] + 28
3  AVFoundation                   0x18a4d0a24 +[AVOutputContext sharedAudioPresentationOutputContext] + 40
4  MediaPlayer                    0x195deb1cc -[MPAVLightweightRoutingController pickedRoutes] + 68
5  MediaPlayer                    0x195e04338 -[MPVolumeView _setShowsVolumeSlider:] + 96
6  MediaPlayer                    0x195e02ad4 -[MPVolumeView layoutSubviews] + 208
7  UIKit                          0x18e593770 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1420
8  QuartzCore                     0x188b3525c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184
9  QuartzCore                     0x188b393ec CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 324
10 QuartzCore                     0x188aa5aa0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 320
11 QuartzCore                     0x188acd5d0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 580
12 QuartzCore                     0x188acdd10 CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 244
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1845e457c _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 572
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1845e42cc _pthread_exit + 88
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1845e40d4 _pthread_wqthread + 1472
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1845e3b08 start_wqthread + 4
```

The Crashlytics wrote:

> This crash has non-main threads that appear to use UIKit classes or
>   functions. Generally speaking, it is only safe to use UIKit from the
>   main thread. Calling into UIKit from background threads can cause
>   unpredictable behavior (like crashes!). Please double check that all
>   of your code (that is not on the main thread) has been explicitly
>   marked as safe to use in the background by Apple.

But we don't use other threads in app.

Crashlytics logs:

> Crashed: Thread 0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x184370910
>   objc_msgSend + 16 1  AVFoundation                   0x18ad241bc
>   +[AVOutputContext(FigRoutingContext) currentRoutingContextFactory] + 56 2  AVFoundation                   0x18ad1ee28
>   +[AVFigRoutingContextOutputContextImpl sharedAudioPresentationOutputContext] + 28 3  AVFoundation
>   0x18acb4a24 +[AVOutputContext sharedAudioPresentationOutputContext] +
>   40 4  MediaPlayer                    0x1965cf1cc
>   -[MPAVLightweightRoutingController pickedRoutes] + 68 5  MediaPlayer                    0x1965e8338 -[MPVolumeView _setShowsVolumeSlider:] + 96 6  MediaPlayer
>   0x1965e6ad4 -[MPVolumeView layoutSubviews] + 208 7  UIKit
>   0x18ed77770 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1420
>   8  QuartzCore                     0x18931925c -[CALayer
>   layoutSublayers] + 184 9  QuartzCore                     0x18931d3ec
>   CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 324 10 QuartzCore
>   0x189289aa0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 320 11
>   QuartzCore                     0x1892b15d0 CA::Transaction::commit() +
>   580 12 QuartzCore                     0x1892b1d10
>   CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 244 13
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184dc857c _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 572
>   14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184dc82cc _pthread_exit + 88 15
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184dc80d4 _pthread_wqthread + 1472 16
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184dc7b08 start_wqthread + 4

Init code:

```
self.volumeView = MPVolumeView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 2,
                                                                     width: 52.0,
                                                                     height: 30.0))
self.volumeView?.showsVolumeSlider = false            self.volumeView?.showsRouteButton = true

self.volumeView?.setRouteButtonImage(UIImage.init(named: "streaming_icon"), for: .normal)
self.volumeView?.setRouteButtonImage(UIImage.init(named: "selected_streaming_icon"), for: .selected)

self.volumeView.sizeToFit()
```

Please help resolve this issue.

Comment: We see the same crash in our streaming app, any success on this? Have you contacted Apple? What I have seen it seems related to the iOS 11.3 release

Comment: @DoubleT, We think, that this issue occurs when user set an app to the background mode. Perhaps this is the only clue. 
I will write to Apple about this issue.

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/312256#312256

Comment: I created a TSI (technical support incident) ticket to Apple to get some understanding in what seems to be causing the crashes. I'll let you know when they answer.

Comment: Thank you. I will wait for response.

Answer (score 1):

I have contacted Apple and they have verified my theory that MPVolumeView performs UI layout changes on a background thread.

Bug report created.

Update 2018-05-30:
Engineering has determined that your bug report (40594280) is a duplicate of 39309134 and will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same crash condition using MPVolumeView and AVPlayer.
With other weird things going on, like the volume slider disappearing.

The issues go away if I set the AVPlayer object attribute 'allowsExternalPlayback' to false.

```
player.allowsExternalPlayback = false
```

Seems strange but it worked.

Comment: I have checked this case. 
When I disabled allowsExternalPlayback, an AirPlay logic doesn't work.
So, this case doesn't work.